# No 'install code' in command palette in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I can't save the file in vscode and it says:

Unable to write file 'vscode-remote://ssh-remote (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open

https://snipboard.io/68K0NZ.jpg

So I tried to click the 'uninstall code': https://snipboard.io/czCVpN.jpg

But there is no 'install code': https://snipboard.io/bFGZc9.jpg

What should I do?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: are you on macOS? What's the OS of your host machine, and of the remote machine you are trying to connect to? Actually, why did you need to run this command when using the SSH remote extension at all?

Comment: also, please use the Stack Overflow image hosting instead of snipboard.io.